# Access array in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a JSON reply, like following:

```
[{
  "order_id": "12",
  "customer": "user user",
  "status": "Pending",
  "date_added": "02\/09\/2012",
  "total": "$500.00",
  "action": [{
    "text": "View",
    "href": "http:\/\/localhost\/oc\/admin\/index.php?route=sale\/order\/info&amp;token=92a80574e5fcbf3e2d021404cfaae1a4&amp;order_id=12"
  }]
}]
```

have a look on action key, it's value is again an array. I am trying to get action key values by following code but it is showing undefined to me

```
function (data) {
  if (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      $('div.dashboard-content table.list tbody tr:first').before(
        '<tr id="' + 
        data[i]['order_id'] + 
        '"><td class="right">' + 
        data[i]['order_id'] + 
        '</td><td class="left">' + 
        data[i]['customer'] + 
        '</td><td class="left">' + 
        data[i]['status'] + 
        '</td><td class="left">' + 
        data[i]['date_added'] + 
        '</td><td class="right">' + 
        data[i]['total'] + 
        '</td><td class="right"> [<a href="' + 
        data[i]['action']['href'] + '">' + 
        data[i]['action']['text'] + 
        '</a>]</td></tr>'
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me.? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is terribly unclear.

Comment: Mother of gawd, those strings are almost 1/10 as long as the ones I use in my code. I see why some people dim my code "un-reviewable". On a side-note, you can do line breaks in JS inside strings escaping them with \ at the end of the line or simply line break at the `+` signs which doesn't affect the output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can access a specific value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-access-a-specific-value)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like you said, `action` is an array. Thus, you can't access it using `data[i]['action']['href']`. You have to use a subscript to indicate the position of the array that you want. For example, to access the first position, you'd use:

```
var href = data[i].action[0].href;
var text = data[i].action[0].text;
```

Answer (score 3):

`action` is an array containing an object with a property called text. Change:

```
data[i]['action']['text']
```

to:

```
data[i]['action'][0]['text']
```